# Font-Awesome: @fa-circle-o - how do I define the thickness of the outline?

Tags: css, svg, less, font-awesome

I haven't been able to find an answer to this question, but perhaps someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to create a stacked icon with a thin (1px) circular line with a transparent fill around a "fa-users" icon.

my code is:

`.HTML
    <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x fa-inverse"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-users fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>`

`variables.less
    @fa-border-color:     #8CC63E;
    @fa-inverse:          #8CC63E;
    @fa-li-width:         1px;`

This mostly works, except I can't find where to adjust the line thickness of the outline. ("@fa-li-width:" doesn't appear to have anything to do with outline thickness.) I can't find the adjustment in variables.less, stacked.less, nor did anything look promising in any of the other .less files. Any suggestions?

Granted, the easiest solution would be to just create an .svg from Sketch, but I'd prefer to use code-based design wherever possible.

(I have some lovely screen grabs to illustrate my situation, but not enough reputation. Hopefully I was clear enough in my text).

Comment: `@fa-li-width` applies only to [`.fa-li` class](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/a65bd93d81e9e6bd5ebfa41757a4474960b973b4/less/list.less) and it's actually more about `margin` rather than a `border`/`outline` thing. So basically you have to explicitly define your own style if need to an change an ordinal icon border (e.g. `.fa {border: 99px solid red}`) since the library itself [does not let you to do so](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/2649d91d18629bab071449b3bc4cb02761037a57/less/bordered-pulled.less#L6) via any variable.

Comment: Thanks for that. OK, it does seem best not to 'stack' using Font-Awesome, but instead style a <div> with a rounded border. That works quite well. Thanks for taking the time to answer.